# React Native dynamic custom select picker for IOS & Android

Tags: react-native, picker

I need a custom generic select picker for ios and android to react-native. How I'll develop a custom picker to use my all components.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 files `Select.android.js` and `Select.ios.js` in your components folder (or something else) for each OS, and import your Select component by
`import Select from 'components/Select'`